# How to write the cocoon delete link with an icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, cocoon-gem

I'm using rails 5, gem 'cocoon' and 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' v.4.0.0.
I want to exchange below "Delete" for link_to_remove_association with a bootstrap trash icon.

```
<%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", f, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

```
<%= link_to_remove_association, f, do %>        
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

I tried as above, but the syntac errors shows:

> "syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block ...nk_to_remove_association, f, do @output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^~
> syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^~~~~~"

How should I write correctly?

Comment: There is a typo: you removed the "Delete" but not the following comma. Is that the exact code you have? because that will generate an error indeed.

Comment: Yes, there is no error with <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", f, class: 'btn btn-danger' %> but have syntax eroors with glyphicon one. There is surely a typo, but I do not know, how I can write it correctly. I already tried without "," too.

Comment: Remove the comma directly following the link_to_remove_association

Comment: Thanks, nathanvda! I removed the both commas, then the problem was solved.    `<%= link_to_remove_association f do %>        
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem:

```
<%= link_to_remove_association '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>'.html_safe, f, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Comment: Because I could not solve my problem with do...end syntax.

Comment: _In your answer_.